# How to send an E-mail over an iOS app using Swift?

Tags: ios

I would like to allow users to send me emails  directly through my app, and am wondering if this is possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best and most simple way is to bring up the send email view (or even mailto:) with your  app specific email to receive comments and requests on.

Another option is to design a web page that has a couple of fields for information and then hooking it up with PHP.

Just about anything works, it all depends on how you balance user experience and easy of implementation.

Comment: Ok thanks for opening my mind a little :)